# How create URL rewrite for category

Tags: category, url, overrides

I create category:

```
 $category->setName(self::CATEGORY_AZ_NAME)
            ->setUrlKey('...')
            ->setUrlPath('...')
            ->setIsActive(1)
            ->setDisplayMode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PRODUCT)
            ->setIsAnchor(0)
            ->setStoreId(0)
            ->setPath($rootCategory->getPath())
            ->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId())
            ->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
            ->setInitialSetupFag(true)
            ->save();
```

But on a front this category have wrong link.
I think that there are URL rewrite not created.

How can i create URL REWRITE for this category?

Comment: Did you check the rewrite table if it was added? And did you reindex after running this script?

Comment: yes you are right, i see it in "URL Rewrite Management" -this all OK. And i add code                                           $reindex = array('catalog_category_product', 'catalog_url');
        foreach ($reindex as $index) {
            Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode($index)->reindexAll();
        }                                        But in front for this category URL = catalog/category/view/

Comment: @Ratio, so you solved the problem yourself? Then would you please add your solution as an answer (answer your own question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set the parent id.
Also you don't need to set the `url_path`. It will be calculated.
So your script should look like this:

```
$category->setName(self::CATEGORY_AZ_NAME)
        ->setUrlKey('...')
        ->setIsActive(1)
        ->setDisplayMode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PRODUCT)
        ->setIsAnchor(0)
        ->setStoreId(0)
        ->setParentId($rootCategory->getId())
        ->setPath($rootCategory->getPath())
        ->setAttributeSetId($category->getDefaultAttributeSetId())
        ->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
        ->setInitialSetupFag(true)
        ->save();
```

Also I think `setInitialSetupFag` has no effect.

Comment: How to do with Default URL Rewrite Management for Main Category, Is Possible?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you dont use the Url management magento default functionality.I had used below link for category redirect

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/custom-redirect-category-page-magento